# Windows 8.1 start screen backgrounds file location

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, screensaver, start-screen

In Windows 8, the start screen backgrounds used to be in the imageres.dll file, but as of 8.1 they're not.
Does anyone know where the start screen backgrounds are housed in Windows 8.1?

If not, is someone using Windows 8 willing to share a png with me?

Comment: Try this link: http://superuser.com/questions/525310/windows-8-start-screen-wallpaper-file-location.  There are a few .dll files that start with the word 'image.'  Try opening all of them if the imageres.dll doesn't work.

Comment: look inside the **TWinui.dll**. The is the core of the new UI. Maybe it includes the pictures as resources.